# query work on phpmyadmin for any limit value ex: `10 OFFSET 3`. But php support only `10 OFFSET 0`

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a mysql query for get notification of my social media network. But it worked well in phpmyadmin with no errors. I've paste it to my php code and worked for `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`. But not working for `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2` or `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 3`... . I've faced to below error message.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

If some one want my query, this is it

```
$query = '
    SELECT
        `bell`.`bell_type`,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`cat`.`cat_firstname` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `bell`.`bell_date` DESC), ",", 1 ) 
            AS firstname,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`bell`.`bell_date` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `bell`.`bell_date` DESC), ",", 1 ) 
            AS belldate,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`bell`.`bell_seen` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `bell`.`bell_date` DESC), ",", 1 ) 
            AS bellseen,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`cat`.`cat_id` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `bell`.`bell_date` DESC), ",", 1 ) 
            AS catid,
        IF(`meaw`.`meaw_content`!="",`meaw`.`meaw_content`,`meaw`.`meaw_type`)
            AS bellcontent,
        COUNT(CONCAT(`bell`.`bell_content`,"-", `bell`.`bell_type`))
            AS bellcount,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`bell`.`bell_link` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `bell`.`bell_date` DESC), ",", 1 )
            AS belllink
        FROM `bell`
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `cat` ON
            `bell`.`bell_with` = `cat`.`cat_id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `meaw` ON
            `bell`.`bell_content` = `meaw`.`meaw_id`
        WHERE
            `bell`.`bell_cat`="'.$catid.'"
        GROUP BY
            CONCAT(`bell`.`bell_content`,"-", `bell`.`bell_type`)
        ORDER BY
            FIELD(`bell`.`bell_seen`,"0","1"), belldate DESC
        LIMIT
            10 OFFSET '.$page;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose in this case your `$page` variable is an empty string. The last line of your query then becomes `LIMIT 10 OFFSET '` and this is obviously the MariaDB syntax violation. Try to check if this it's `empty` prior to running the query and if it does - simply assign 0 to it and then run the query.

Comment: I've replaced `OFFSET '.$page;` to `OFFSET 10';` . Error is the same. But when I replaced it to  `OFFSET 0';` first 10 rows appearing. Thank you for your answer. But it was not worked.

Comment: The error is the same you've posted above (`...the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`)?

Comment: yes it is. I tried for `LIMIT 10,20` and `LIMIT 20,10`. But nothing changed

Comment: It must be on PHP side. I run the similar query on my side and everything seems to work. Look carefully what yours query looks like before executing.

Comment: I've already checked it by `echo $query` and pasting to phpmyadmin. still not working. I think it is a problem of the server. Thank you for your answers.